# Warning: require_once(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settingserror in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to install a open source PHP application IIS; after installation I am getting the following error:

Warning: require_once(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Kolkata' for '5.5/no DST' instead in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\dotproject\lib\adodb\adodb.inc.php

Answer (score 12):

This has nothing to do with [require_once()](http://docs.php.net/require_once) but with the time/date function you're using in the included script.

see http://docs.php.net/datetime.configuration#ini.date.timezone and http://docs.php.net/timezones

Simplest solution: Put

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata"
```

into your php.ini. Use

```
<?php echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
```

to determine which php.ini you have to edit.

Comment: Or if you don't have access to it, use the date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata") as the message suggests in your code.